# Embedded hazelcast prevents clean shutdown in Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, hazelcast

I have embedded hazelcast (3.8.2) in a Tomcat 7 webapp. On shutdown I'm calling

```
 myInstance.shutdown();
 Hazelcast.shutdownAll();
```

But I'm still getting this error in tomcat logs, which is preventing the clean shutdown of my webapp.  `HazelcastManagedThread` appears to be trying to run a ClisterListenerSupport instance after  the server has stopped.

Am I missing some further cleanup steps I should be adding to my shutdown hook?

```
04-Oct-2017 12:15:08.923 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.stop Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8084"]
04-Oct-2017 12:15:08.952 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.stop Stopping ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
04-Oct-2017 12:15:09.048 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8084"]
04-Oct-2017 12:15:09.049 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
04-Oct-2017 12:15:14.226 INFO [hz.client_0.cluster-] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClusterListenerSupport$1$1]. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
     java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClusterListenerSupport$1$1]. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1327)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForClassLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1313)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1196)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1157)
        at com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClusterListenerSupport$1.run(ClusterListenerSupport.java:235)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
        at com.hazelcast.util.executor.HazelcastManagedThread.executeRun(HazelcastManagedThread.java:64)
        at com.hazelcast.util.executor.HazelcastManagedThread.run(HazelcastManagedThread.java:80)

    Exception in thread "hz.client_0.cluster-" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't overwrite cause with java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClusterListenerSupport$1$1]. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
        at java.lang.Throwable.initCause(Throwable.java:457)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForClassLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1316)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1196)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1157)
        at com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClusterListenerSupport$1.run(ClusterListenerSupport.java:235)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
        at com.hazelcast.util.executor.HazelcastManagedThread.executeRun(HazelcastManagedThread.java:64)
        at com.hazelcast.util.executor.HazelcastManagedThread.run(HazelcastManagedThread.java:80)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForClassLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1315)
        ... 8 more
```

Answer (score 0):

This is hard to fix. The problem is, that Tomcat is already in shutdown mode and the classloader will not load new classes. Hazelcast however uses classes on shutdown for the first time, so they would need to be loaded. Fixing this is actually pretty ugly. You can use Class.forName (or other reflection mechanisms) to load the class. You don't have to store a reference to the class but this will actually force the JVM to load this other depending classes.

Comment: Any idea why Hazelcast is trying to do this after shutdown? This sounds like something I'm doing wrong either on startup or shutdown.

Comment: Just simply because classes are used during shutdown that have never been used before.